# How to go through the matrix and sum elements by a given index?

Tags: python

I am sharing the whole task description to can understand what I mean:

Description
Write a program that finds the maximum sum between two given coordinates in a matrix. The coordinates are provided as a list of pairs, such as '2 3 -4 -2' where '2 3' is the first pair and '-4 -2' is the next one. The first number of the pair is the row coordinate R and the second one is the column coordinate C.

You need to follow a path from R to C and sum up all the values you encounter in cells. For example, with coordinates '2 3' you start from the beginning of the 2nd row and move towards the 3rd column. When you reach the column, you go up because the column coordinate 3 is positive.

With coordinates '-4 -2' you start from the end of the 4th row (because -4 is negative) and move towards the 2nd column. When you reach it, you go down (-2 is negative).

Check the following picture for a clearer idea.

[image]

The path '2 3' yields a sum of 17 which is higher than the sum you obtain by following '-4 -2' (15)

Print the maximum sum you find to the standard output.

Note

You always have to move horizontally in rows and vertically in columns. For example, in the above picture, the correct path with coordinates -4 -2 is 3 -> 2 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2 and NOT 3 -> 4 -> 3 -> 6 -> 2.

Input

On the first line, you receive an integer N - the number of rows in the matrix
On the next N lines, each row of the matrix is given, with columns separated by a space
On the last line, the R and C coordinates are given, separated by spaces

Output

On the only line of output, print the maximum sum found.

Constraints

N will be an integer between 5 and 20, inclusive.
All rows have the exact same length, also between 5 and 20, inclusive.
The R and C coordinates will always be valid and inside the matrix.
The R C pairs will be at least 1 and no more than 20.
Matrix elements will have values in range -5000 and 5000.

Sample Tests

Input

```
6
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7
6 5 4 3 2 1
3 4 5 6 7 8
4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4
3 5 3 -5 -4 -2
```

Output

```
43
```

Input

```
5
1 22 3 41 5 2
2 13 4 -5 6 5
-6 5 9 31 2 8
3 14 5 -6 7 4
4 -5 6 -7 8 7
-3 -3 3 3 4 -3 -4 3
```

Output

```
61
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
rows = int(input())

matrix = []

for _ in range(rows):
    row = list(map(int, input().split()))
    matrix.append(row)

for i in matrix:
    print(i)
```

And yes, I know that this only creates the matrix and it is very easy to be done, but I just don't have an idea how to continue with the next phases of the task description!

I will be more than happy if someone can help me, even an advice will be helpful for me.

Or maybe the matrix that the code above creates is not correct at all!?

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate one sum for a given pair? If so, have you understood the given example in the image?

Comment: Yes, I fully understand the given example in the image. And yes, I am asking how to calculate the sum for a given pair of coordinates. I understand what I should do, but don't know how to do it on code! :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example in the image, the pair is `2, 3`, and the variable `matrix` stores the matrix of numbers. Then you could follow these steps:

1. select the row `2` (note that python index starts at 0, but the index in the matrix starts at 1), with `row = matrix[1]`.
2. use a for loop to accumulate the sum along the row, until the current column reaches matrix column `3`.
3. And finally add the number after moving up.

Below is a sample code that realizes the above steps. Note that it does not consider effect of negative numbers in the pair.

```py
pair = [2, 3]
# NOTE "-1" is due to python index starting at 0.
row = pair[0] - 1
column = pair[1] - 1
matrix_row = matrix[row]
one_sum = 0

# accumulate the row, until reaching the column.
for i in range(column + 1):
    one_sum += matrix_row[i]
# add the number after moving up.
one_sum += matrix[row - 1][column]
```